# Champagne 2 - Fatal error: Call to a member function was_successful() on a non-object

Tags: module, fatal, champagne

Recently I've installed and configured the champagne 2 module from Chris Newton(http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/champagne-2) everything worked fine but when I wanted to send my new campaign I did get a PHP error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function was_successful() on a non-object in ..\system\expressionengine\third_party\champagne\mcp.champagne.php on line 461

When I var dump the $result var from line 461 it will say it's a (boolean)FALSE

Does someone has a solution?

Comment: I will leave this as a comment since nobody else answered (and it's not really answering your question), but I would suggest trying out Postmaster https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster. I have no idea how to solve your issue, but I know I built Postmaster to make sending email campaign easy and reliable for clients. It allows you send campaigns right from channel entries using whatever fields you want, and has many other great uses besides sending emails campaigns. Email support@objectivehtml.com if you have any questions.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me - best you email Mighty Big Robot support about it so they can get it fixed.

Comment: Already emailed the devs that created the module :)
  
Also I will wait for a awnser first before I'll switch to Postmaster but thanks for giving me a alternative Justin!

Comment: Dennis, did you get a resolution to this from the guys at MBR? I'm having the same issue at the moment.

Comment: I've tried to contact them over the past few days trough different methods. I've tried the MBG website, The BarretNewton website and direct e-mailadresses of the Managing partner and Senior Developer but no response.

Therefore I decided to use postmaster from objective HTML also postmaster has a lot of more options.